# PHP multidimensional associative array with a loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a multidimensional associative array but the first array is empty. As you can see the [domain1] array is not showing any associative array items whereas [domain2] is showing the results that should be in the [domain1] array.

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
            $arr1['domain'.$x] = $arr2;
            $arr2['sum'] = $row['domain' . $x];
            $arr2['core'] = ${"d$x"};
        }
```

My results look like this.

```
Array
(
[domain1] => Array
    (
    )

[domain2] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 8
        [core] => 4
    )

[domain3] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 8
        [core] => 3
    )

[domain4] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 8
        [core] => 2
    )

[domain5] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 8
        [core] => 3
    )

[domain6] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 8
        [core] => 6
    )
)
```

Comment: So, what is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: Hi David, as stated: "the [domain1] array is not showing any associative array items whereas [domain2] is showing the results that should be in the [domain1] array." Question/problem answered by JesusTheHun. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the array `$arr1` in the wrong order. Correct order is :

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $arr2 = array();
    $arr2['sum'] = $row['domain' . $x];
    $arr2['core'] = ${"d$x"};
    $arr1['domain'.$x] = $arr2;
}
```